# how do i create a general function to receive a map in go lang?

Tags: go

how can i  pass map data in to a general function (isExist) to check, the given value is exist or not
passing map type may be map[int]int or map[string]string or any

```
func IsExist(text int, data map[interface{}]interface{}) bool {

    for key, _ := range data {

        if data[key] == text {

            return true

        }

    }

    return false

}

func main() {

    var data = make(map[string]int)

    //var data =map[interface {}]interface{}  this case will working fine

    data["a"] = 1

    data["b"] = 2

    fmt.Println(IsExist(2, data))
    //throwing error that 'cannot use data (type map[string]int) as type  map[interface {}]interface {} in argument to IsExist'

}
```

please let me know how can you generalize it?

Comment: Sergio's answer is right, there's no straightforward way to do this kind of generic programming. Also, this compares an `int` to an `interface{}`, which are not comparable, because the `interface{}` could be an `int` or a `string` or a `[]*net.IP` or *anything*. The code seems to be trying to be "generic" while making hard assumptions about the data it's working with. Your loop is also very strange - you take the key and discard the value, so that you can use the key to look up the value. Have you taken the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) by chance? It covers the basics well.

Comment: It would maybe help to know why you want to do this. Usually these kind of questions come from a thinking that is not yet accustomed to `Go`.

Answer (score 2):

Go's type system can't do that. `map[string]int` and `map[interface {}]interface{}` are distinct types. Besides, storage/representation of objects in memory depends on the type. A string has one memory layout. But the very same string, packaged as a `interface{}` - totally different. For the same reasons you can't "cast" a `[]int` to a `[]interface{}`. You have to copy the elements into the new slice.

Same here. Either make your map a `map[interface {}]interface{}` from the start, or copy all key-values pairs to one, prior to the call of the generic function.